# C++ UE4 atlbase.h no such file or directory

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, atl

I've had this issue with my project and I can't for the life of me figure out what to do. Im trying to include the atlbase.h header file, but when I try to build it, it comes up with the following:

```
Cannot open include file: 'atlbase.h': No such file or directory
```

I've tried every solution I could find on google and I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix this.
I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Communtiy Edition 14.27.29112.

I would very much appreciate it if someone could help me to figure this one out.

Comment: Did you make sure that you installed ATL (via the Visual Studio installer)?

Comment: @UnholySheep I included C++ ATL for latest v142 build tools ARM | ARM 64 | x86 & x64 but the weird thing is they keep showing up on the right side like they aren't installed properly, even though the folder exists https://i.imgur.com/SgqnxYM.png

Comment: Have you found where the atlbase.h is? Should be in something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\[edition]\VC\Tools\MSVC\[version like 14.27.29110]\atlmfc\include`

Comment: @SimonMourier I have, its in this directiory for me `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\atlmfc\include` I can see it in there but it still wont include it.

Comment: Then it's a problem in your project. Make sure you have these directories included. When creating a Visual Studio project they should be there by default, but you can force any directory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcpp-directories-property-page?view=vs-2019  Or reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks that fixed it!